# C#: Outlook Mailitem Changed

Tags: c#, outlook-addin, outlook-2010, office-2010, mailitem

i am developing an Outlook AddIn for Outlook 2010 with VS 2010.

When the user opens some Mails, and he changes the focus from one mailitem to another: Is there any event which can give me the currently displayed/focused mailitem?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are interested in the [SelectionChange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869813(v=office.15).aspx) event of the Explorer class. It is fired when the user selects a different or additional Microsoft Outlook item programmatically or by interacting with the user interface.

If you switch between inspectors, you need to handle the [Activate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865363(v=office.15).aspx) event of the Inspector class. It is fired when an inspector becomes the active window, either as a result of user action or through program code.